# What is the best way to install fb pixel in magento 2 ? Using script or with extension!

Tags: facebook-pixel, pixel-tracking

What are the best extensions?!

Answer (score 0):

There is an official extension which does it

https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/532749253576163

> Install the Facebook business extension through your Magento account to help you share online and offline events with Facebook. By sharing these events, you can see how users are interacting with your business. Then you can optimise the targeting and delivery of your Facebook ads to drive more business outcomes.

This tracking is done via a pixel

https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/742478679120153?id=1205376682832142

> The Facebook pixel is an analytics tool that allows you to measure the effectiveness of your advertising by understanding the actions people take on your website.

> You can use the pixel to:

> Make sure that your ads are shown to the right people. Find new customers, or people who have visited a specific page or taken a desired action on your website.

> Drive more sales. Set up automatic bidding to reach people who are more likely to take an action that you care about, such as making a purchase.

> Measure the results of your ads. Better understand the effect of your ads by measuring what happens when people see them.

However there is a lot of setup required. You need to understand how Facebook works in terms of business configuration.